# How to write Boolean Algebra of a CMOS circuit?

Tags: boolean-algebra, nmos, pmos

[image]

How to write the boolean algebra of this circuit?

I am confused with the inverter in the middle .

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to write down a truth table ? Since there seem to be only two inputs `A` and `B`, there can be only 16 possible answers and you may be able to write down the answer *by inspection* of the truth table.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without writing the truth table? @AJN

Comment: Simulate it, find the output when A and B are high and low, draw a truth table, and figure out the Boolean equation.

Comment: What if it is in an exam setting, and I'm unable to simulate it? @KingDuken

Comment: @Dugong98 Disregard my comment. I didn't see the feedback connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a latch, because of the feedback.

And timing, in the moderate picoseconds, will matter.

The A input serves as enable for Output Pulldown, when A is high; when A is low, the Output Pullup is allowed.

Comment: Can you explain a little further?

Comment: How does a latch or feedback system works?

Comment: What controls the switch Q4 & Q5?

Comment: @anlogsystemsrf please correct me if I am wrong, there is no digital feedback present in this static CMOS/PassTransistorLogic design, this simplifies out to be a 9-Transistor implementation of XOR boolean function.

https://imgur.com/a/F0V4K66